# XSS inside in a Javascript string where < and > are allowed, but " and / are filtered

Tags: xss

I need help with the following.
I have this Javascript source code:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var settings = {"Url":"someValue","Variable":{"message":"[injection point]"}};
/* ]]> */
</script>
```

Now I want to inject Javascript at `[injection point]` in the JSON string. The problem is that I can't use `"` and `/`. I can use all other chars, such as `<` or `>`.

Comment: try encoding it

Comment: i tried but it doesnt work

Comment: `'` and `\`` are valid string delimiters in JS. good luck on the slash.

Comment: ok i get something to work without slashes: <iframe src=javascript:alert();> - now i just need to work within the code :)

Comment: okay - the problem is, that the " is escaped and not complete filtered out - maybe this helps ...

Comment: ok - so now i have an idea - whats with \n?